# How to dynamically display time data stream on matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm using matplotlib to display data saved on a csv file periodically,
now the data is plotted well but the time axis is hardly moving, in fact 
the script is trying to show all the data stored on that file, I want to see only latest data and be able to scrol horizontaly to see older data 
this is a part of the script :

```
style.use('grayscale')

fig = plt.figure()
ax0= fig.add_subplot(511)


def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('filelocation','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []

    for line in lines :
        if len(line)>1:
            time0 , quantity0 = line.split (',')
            xs.append(dt.datetime.strptime(time0,'%H:%M:%S.%f'))
            ys.append(quantity0)

    ax0.clear()
    ax0.plot(xs,ys)


xs = matplotlib.dates.date2num(xs)
hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax0.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0))
ax0.set_ylabel('risk')
ax0.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
ani =  animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis ='y' , scilimits = (0,0))
plt.show()
plt.clear()
```

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem with this code but have you tried using `ax0.set_xlim` to move the x axis to show the window of data you want to view?

Comment: No, would that make it move automatically from left to right as data keeps coming ?

Comment: OK.  I don't quite understand what you're trying to do then.  You want to make it interactive?  Is there any chance you can create some fake data so that your example above is completely reproducible?

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVQ2Guypp_M) video show it all, the first 7seconds show how the data keep coming from right while its not flowing from the left side, thats exacly my case and issue, the rest of the video (after the 7th sec ) shows how i want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

From that video, it looks like you want something like the following - I can still see a scrolling window in the video you posted so I'm still a little confused as to what you want.  This uses `fig.canvas.draw` but there are other options using the matplotlib animation module (you didn't specify that it had to be using that module).

```
import numpy as np, time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import matplotlib
matplotlib.interactive(True)

rest_time = 0.001
data_stream = np.random.randn(200)

# Define the width of the viewing window (xaxis limits), 
# and the number of points to be displayed until a scrolling window starts
window_width = 40
n = 60

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plotted_data, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo-', lw = 1.5)

x = []
y = []

ax.set_xlim([0, window_width])
ax.set_ylim([-4, 4])

for t, d in enumerate(data_stream):

    x.append(t)
    y.append(d)

    plotted_data.set_xdata(x)
    plotted_data.set_ydata(y)

    if t > window_width:
        ax.set_xlim([0, t])

    if len(x) > n:
        ax.set_xlim([t-n, t])

    time.sleep(rest_time)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Ok that could be a solution, in my case i have a csv file contain two columns Time,value ... How can this solution work for me as i have time in the x axis .. If you want i can upload an example file from where i take data

Comment: Change the for-loop to `for t, d in zip(times, values):` where `times` is an array of times you want to plot (the Time column of your dataset) and `values` is an array of the values you want to plot.